# How to programmatically upload images to flickr using flickr API and PHP

Tags: php, api, flickr

I have to start working on a script to upload images to flickr following the documentation [here](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/upload.api.html) but I can't understand how to authenticate following the instruction [here](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.spec.html).

Can anyone with experience with that tell me the steps I need to follow for it? for example:

should I have to authorise the app before to start doing uploads?
  should I have to authenticate before every single upload?
  how can I compose the url to get the signature? this is what I am using ATM but is asking me for a callback url I can't see in this doc page:

```
'http://flickr.com/services/auth/?api_key='.$KEY.'&perms=write&api_sig='.md5($SECRET.'api_key'.$KEY.'permswrite');
```

thanks

Comment: Yes. No. Use one of the Flickr PHP libraries that do it for you.

Comment: phpFlickr was last updated 2 years ago and I'd like to have more control on this. I just need to understand how to create the url to send the user to authorize his own APP.

Comment: The API probably hasn't been updated in longer (especially since they were probably still active when Yahoo decided to list them). Even if you don't want to use the libs, you can still read their code to see how to use the API.